# Understanding an expression from Tom Bank's book of Modern Quantum Field Theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, propagator, classical-field-theory

In Tom Bank's book Modern Quantum Field Theory he says,

> Consider a classical machine (an emission source) that has probability amplitude $J_E(x)$ of producing a particle at position $x$ in space-time, and an absorption source, which has amplitude $J_A(x)$ to absorb the particle. Assume that the particle propagates freely between emission and absorption, and has mass $m$. The standard rules of quantum mechanics tell us that the amplitude (to leading order in perturbation theory in
>   the sources) for the entire process is (remember our natural units!)
>   $$A_{AE}=\int d^4x d^4y\langle x|e^{ −iH(x^0 −y^0)}|y\rangle J_A(x)J_E(y),\tag{1}$$
>   where $|x\rangle$ is the state of the particle at spatial position $x$.

What does he have in mind when he says "*by standard rules of quantum mechanics*"? In other words, by which standard rules of QM did he obtain Eqn.(1)?

Comment: $\langle x | e^{-i H(x^0-y^0)} | y \rangle$ is the amplitude for the particle to propagate from position $y$ to position $x$. Multiplying by $J_A(x) J_E(y)$ gives the probability that a particle is emitted at $y$, propagates for time $x^0-y^0$, and is absorbed at $x$.  Summing over $x$ and $y$ gives the total emission-absorbtion probability.

Comment: @user81003 That should be an answer, not a comment.